# Firebase Database on Google App Engine using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a backend module that needs to write multiple nodes on Firebase Database.
This works perfectly locally (localhost) but once deployed on AppEngine, no nodes are created, but the server returns a 200.

As stated in the documentation, I have configured `appengine-web.xml` so the App Engine backend uses manual scaling

```
<manual-scaling>
<instances>1</instances>
</manual-scaling>
```

Below my servlet

```
public class UseCaseServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    FirebaseUtils.initFirebase(getServletContext());

    ArrayList<User> users = getSomeUsers();
    for(User user :users){
        writeUserNodeAsTrue(user);
    }

    writeOverallServiceStatus();
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
}

private void writeUserNodeAsTrue(User user) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(user.id);
    myRef.setValue(true);
}

private void writeOverallServiceStatus(){
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef =      database.getReference("service_status");
    myRef.setValue(true);
}
}
```

This code works perfectly locally, but not on app engine.
I tried using Tasks or Transaction, but I should be missing something I guess.

Any help would be more than appreciated :)
Cheers

For more information :

-initFirebase() follows this tutorial recommendation
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

```
public static void initFirebase(ServletContext servletContext){
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setServiceAccount(servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/youApp-xxxxxxx.json"))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com/")
            .build();
    try {
        FirebaseApp.getInstance();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.info("doesn't exist...");
    }
    try {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.info("already exists...");
    }
}
```

- getSomeUsers() returns an array of String (nothing interesting)

Comment: What exactly does FirebaseUtils.initFirebase() do?  What is not working?  Have you tried adding logging to see if anything is executing the way you expect, such as the result of initialization, or the value of getSomeUsers()?  What exactly are you doing to "run locally"?

Comment: The information you asked is on the main post (updated). `Run locally` means, through Android studio, running the module so it can be tested locally (on localhost)

Comment: Check that you can actually read the resource file that contains the service account.  Check that you can actually log messages and read them in the GAE console (I don't know what your "Log" class is - why aren't you using the servlet context logger?).  At one point you are calling getInstance() before initializeApp() - that doesn't make sense.  You have to init before you can get an instance.  You probably don't want to initialize on every invocation of the servlet - it should be just once for the entire GAE instance.  Are you sure that getSomeUsers() is actually returning a non-empty list?

Comment: One other thing you should know - there is a known problem with the Firebase admin SDK on GAE standard instances where Firebase will apparently stop working 24 hours after the instance is started.  I'd actually recommend using a flexible GAE instance, even though it's in beta.  I've personally had more luck with that.